# Connection pool to database without application server in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, db2, connection, pool

I'm developing an application in java that will run without an application server (it's not a web application).
Usually, application servers provides database connection pool, which is faster than create a new connection each time you need to run a query.

I would like to know if there's something similar when developing desktop applications.

My project connects to database (DB2) and Elastic Search. Both needs a connection creation. Something that works with both would be great.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: You can still create a connection pool for a desktop application. Please advise on why you would not be able to create one?

Comment: I'm able to create one, but my application listen a JMS queue and for each message it need to enrich the data queriyng a database and inserting this data on elasticsearch. Depending of the quantity of messages are comming, like 1000 messages in 2 minutes, I think the best should work with a pool instead of create new 1000 database and elasticsearch connections. I'm just looking for a better performance.

Comment: You could use threads and assign a few connections say 100 and then each thread can block until it gets a notification to unblock at which point it can check if connections are available etc and carry on?

Comment: Take a look on that: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Apache Commons DBCP will solve with problem with JDBC connection pool.

Thank you "Rafael Moita" for the tip.